# Excel/SQL , Exclude last "," in named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of values that I use for a `where` clause in my excel sheet sql statement.

However the last value always have that ending `,`.

Is there anyway I can changed my named range to exclude the last comma?

**What I tried:**

`"'"&$A6&"'"` to replace the last row `,` with this `'AP'`. 
However my named ranges shows in alphabetical order when I use it in my where clause. So `'AP'` won't be the last value.

I have a list of values like below:

```
+--------+
| 'TOR', |
| 'TOR', |
| 'TOR', |
| '1',   |
| '1',   |
| 'AP',  |
+--------+
```

This is the formula I use:

```
=OFFSET(Nodes2!$F$2,0,0,COUNTA(Nodes2!$F:$F),1)
```

my where clause:

```
position in "&" ("&textjoinifs(CHAR(10),24,2,namedrange)&")"
```

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading. Are you using `Formula` or `VBA` for this? or maybe using the `Formula` in your `VBA`?

Comment: Does the original input list include the comma, or is that being added by your reference code?  If the latter, can you please included that code.

Comment: Formula for my named range. The SQL statement is ran through vba.

Comment: the original input list does not include comma, I add `'name',` to each one using a formula. Then i add a final formula to have `'name'`

Comment: How are you building the SQL?  Just take it out, `strWhere=xyz,` `strWhere=left(strWhere,len(strWhere)-1)`

Comment: Hey @Nathan_Sav , can i make this adjustment to my where clause? See my edit . I use a formula for my where clause.

Comment: `left(textjoinifs(CHAR(10),24,2,namedrange),len(textjoinifs(CHAR(10),24,2,namedrange)&")")-1)` I'd use a variable for the join results, then `left(strWhere,len(strWhere)-1)`

Comment: sigh why cant i get this work! I'm still getting `'TOR',` as my end of my range. this is my current where clause, `position in "&" ("&left(textjoinifs(CHAR(10),24,2,bookName2),len(textjoinifs(CHAR(10),24,2,bookName2)&")")-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a range which is an array already, use `Join` instead of manual concatenation. Just keep your actual values in the cell and don't add `,` or `'` in the cell itself.

See the code comments for details.

---

```
Sub test()

    Dim arr
    Dim strResult  As String

    '/ Get the range data into an array
    arr = Sheet1.Range("TestNamedRange")

    '/ Transpose the array , so you end up with one dimension
    arr = Application.Transpose(arr)

    '/ Join the array. Specify whatever delimeter you want e.g. ','
    strResult = "'" & Join(arr, "','") & "'"

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this. 1) is "TestNamedRange" my named range before any formulas have been applied to it? 2) where will this code output the results?

Comment: 1. Testnamedrange is your named range with SQL predicate values.  2. This is just a test sub, `strResult` will contain the final string. Convert it to a function if you need to consume it inside another routine.

Comment: can we just spit out str result to a specified cell ? I want to spit it out to a cell and use that as my where clause.

Comment: you can, just search `how to create a UDF in VBA`.

Answer (score 0):

This very basic code will trim any commas off the end of a string:

```
Function TrimTrailingCommas(ByVal Text As String) As String
    While Right(Text, 1) = "," 'When the last character is a comma
        Text = Left(Text, Len(Text) - 1) 'Remove it
    Wend 'Repeat until the last character is not a comma
    TrimTrailingCommas = Text 'Return the trimmed text
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=Left(Cell,Len(Cell)-1)
```

Trims the last character.

For the VBA Version (I freehand wrote this, might have a syntax error):

```
Function RemoveLastComma (InputString as String)
    RemoveLastComma = Application.Worksheetfunction.Left(InputString ,Len(InputString)-1)
End Function
```